# Firefox browser issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I have write basic code in angularJS to print the user inputs. Its working in chrome but not in firefox. Attached html and js file. Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

```js
var application = angular.module('mainApp', []);
application.controller('app', function($scope){
 $scope.Inputs = [];
 $scope.searchEnter = function() {
  if(event.which == 13 && $scope.Input != "")
  {
   $scope.addInput();
  }
 };
 $scope.addInput = function(){
  $scope.Inputs.push($scope.Input);
  $scope.Input = '';
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>get the input from user and print on page</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="app">
     <h2 style="color:blue"> Enter the input value</h2>
     <input type="text" ng-model="Input" ng-keyup="searchEnter()">
     <div id="InputsToPrint">
      <ol>
       <li style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:capitalize; font-style=italic; color:green" ng-repeat="firstInput in Inputs">
        {{firstInput}}
       </li>
      </ol>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In firefox input values not print in page.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pass `event` object to function. You should pass `$event`(event object) variable while calling `searchEnter` method. Its working in chrome because, he is smart enough to get event object without even passing it as a parameter.

```
ng-keyup="searchEnter($event)"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.searchEnter = function(e) { //firefox needs event to be taken as parameter
    if( !e ) e = window.event; // <-- its needed for IE
    if(e.which == 13 && $scope.Input != "") {
        $scope.addInput();
    }
};
```

Comment: @Jayasree Pleased to hear that, please accept an answer, so that it would help others as well. Thanks :-)